# VB.net DataGridView rounding decimal to integer

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datagridview, visual-studio-2022

I'm querying from an SQLite database and loading the values into a DataGridView in vb.net

Below is the subroutine I'm using to do the load. The sql query returns correct decimal values for "subtotal" and "price". However, sometimes the DataGridView converts those columns to integers!

This seems to be driven by the first record, because if the first record is a decimal or zero then the rest of the values in the column will show correctly. But if the first record is a non-zero whole number then all the values in the column get rounded to the nearest whole number.

I've tried adding `.ValueType = GetType(Double)` to each of those columns (tried both before and after loading  but to no avail.

Any ideas? How can I force the DataGridView to always recognize this column as a decimal?

```
    Public Sub reload_SalesTicketItems(ByVal sql As String, ByVal DGV As Object)
    Try
        Strconnection.Open()
        Using strcon As SQLiteConnection = Strconnection()
            ds_SalesTicketItems = New DataSet

            Using cmd = New SQLiteCommand
                With cmd
                    .Connection = strcon
                    .CommandText = sql
                End With
                Using da As New SQLiteDataAdapter
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd
                    da.Fill(ds_SalesTicketItems, "Items")

                    With DGV
                        .Columns("subtotal").ValueType = GetType(Double)
                        .Columns("price").ValueType = GetType(Double)

                        .DataSource = ds_SalesTicketItems
                        .DataMember = "Items"
                    End With
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("ERROR [34]: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

OK if non-zero decimal for first value:

[image]

OK if zero for first value:

[image]

Wrong if non-zero whole number for first value (same data, just queried in a different order):

[image]

Comment: A `DataGridView` isn't going to spontaneously change the data type of bound data. The first thing to do is to actually look at your data source. After populating the `DataTable`, look at the `DataType` property of each column to see what the data actually is. Once we know that, we can go from there. Please update the question with that information.

Comment: By the way, there's no point creating a `DataSet` when all you need is a `DataTable`. Just create a `DataTable` and use that directly. If you do bind a `DataSet`, set the `DataMember` before the `DataSource`, just as you would set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` before the `DataSource` in a `ComboBox` or `ListBox`. You should aoso bind the data via a `BindingSource`, which you can add in the designer.

Comment: Also, I don't think you should be using Hungarian Notation at all but, if you do, at least make it make sense. Why would you prefix a variable name with "str" when it's not type `string`? Also, what on earth are you doing with that connection? You're opening a connection but never closing it when you don't need to open it at all. It's also not clear whether `Strconnection` is a field or a method. Why do you need `Strconnection` and `strconn`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a work-around by adjusting my query to include copies of the decimal columns formatted as strings, for example:
`CASE WHEN subtotal IS NOT NULL THEN printf("%.2f", subtotal) ELSE "" END AS subtotal2`

...but this feels like a band-aid. I would prefer to be able to fix it in vb.net instead of having to manipulate the queries.